# Convert columns that share a match to row

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have a file with the following structure:

```
Locus7625186 GO0004866
Locus7625186 GO0010951
Locus7625186 GO0005615
Locus7625186 GO0016021
Locus7360093 GO0004712
Locus7360093 GO0007093
Locus1507198 GO0044212
Locus1507198 GO0045944
Locus1507198 GO0005634
Locus1507198 GO0036464
Locus1507198 GO0046982
```

I need to convert it to this:

```
Locus7625186 GO0004866 GO0010951 GO0005615 GO0016021
Locus7360093 GO0004712 GO0007093
Locus1507198 GO0044212 GO0045944 GO0005634 GO0036464 GO0046982
```

Note that the number of `GOxxxxxxx` sharing the same first column match varies.

Comment: I assume the first words always come in groups, like in your example?

Answer (score 5):

With [GNU Datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)

```
$ datamash -W groupby 1 collapse 2 < file | sed 's/,/ /g'
Locus7625186    GO0004866 GO0010951 GO0005615 GO0016021
Locus7360093    GO0004712 GO0007093
Locus1507198    GO0044212 GO0045944 GO0005634 GO0036464 GO0046982
```

(you may omit the pipe through sed if you don't mind the default comma separators).

Comment: Nothing beats a specialized tool +1

Answer (score 2):

You may approach this using the `GNU sed` stream editor:

```
sed -Ee '
   :a
      $!N
      s/^((\S+)\s.*)\n\2(\s.*)/\1\3/
   ta
   P;D
' file
```

**Results**

```
Locus7625186 GO0004866 GO0010951 GO0005615 GO0016021
Locus7360093 GO0004712 GO0007093
Locus1507198 GO0044212 GO0045944 GO0005634 GO0036464 GO0046982
```

This can be done using `POSIX sed` too:

```
sed -e '
   :a
      $!N
      s/^\(\([^[:space:]]\{1,\}\)[[:space:]].*\)\n\2\([[:space:]].*\)/\1\3/
   ta
   P;D
' file
```

Comment: You can do it that way without jump mark and `t` branching by using the `D` for looping, making the script more readable. See the explanation of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your key values are grouped as in your sample input:

```
$ awk '
    $1 != prev { printf "%s%s", ors, $1; prev=$1; ors=ORS }
    { printf " %s", $2 }
    END { print "" }
' file
Locus7625186 GO0004866 GO0010951 GO0005615 GO0016021
Locus7360093 GO0004712 GO0007093
Locus1507198 GO0044212 GO0045944 GO0005634 GO0036464 GO0046982
```

If they aren't then sort the file first.

Answer (score 1):

Another `sed` approach, compact, portable and bizarre:

```
sed 'N;/^\(.*\)\( .*\)\(\n\1\)/!P;s//\3\2/;D'
```

- It uses the `N;P;D` approach to always have two lines in pattern space, so it begins with `N` to append the next line
- `/^\(.*\) .*\n\1/` matches a line starting with some word, a whitespace, another word a newline and the initial word repeated, thus the two lines in the buffer share their first (`Locus`) word. If this is not the case (`!`), `P`rint the first line, because it is complete and we can later get rid of it with `D`
- But if the line matches, so we have two lines with the same first word and can do a replacement removing the newline and the repeated word. That's why I put two more subgroups in the address pattern for the `P`, so now I don't have to repeat it, but reuse it by having an empty pattern
- Now comes the trick: I replace `first second\nfirst` with `\nfirst second`, so the pattern space has an empty first line followed by the second line with the first word and all second word we had so far. The following `D` will now delete the empty first line and continue with the line colleted so far. By including the `\n` in the `\3` match we don't need `\n` in the replacement, which would not be portable.

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '!a[$1]{b[++p]=$1; a[$1]=$2;next} {a[$1]=sprintf("%s%s%s", a[$1], OFS, $2)} END {for (i=1; i<=p; i++) print b[i], a[b[i]]}' file
```

based in this post [how to group rows according to the first field/element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22943445/shell-script-how-to-group-rows-according-to-the-first-field-element-in-each-row)

Comment: For robustness `!a[$1]` should be `!($1 in a)` and `a[$1]=sprintf("%s%s%s", a[$1], OFS, $2)` can be written as just `a[$1] = a[$1] OFS $2`, the sprintf is adding no value.

Comment: `awk '!($1 in a){b[++p]=$1; a[$1]=$2;next} {a[$1] = a[$1] OFS $2} END {for (i=1; i<=p; i++) print b[i], a[b[i]]}' file`
yes it works and is more efficient. Could you please explain how the whole expression works?

Comment: !($1 in a) is testing if $1 exists as an index in a[] while !a[$1] is testing if the **value** that exists in a[] at a[$1] is neither zero nor null and as a side effect creates that index in a. The latter would fail if $2 was 0, for example. a[$1] = a[$1] OFS $2 is just assigning a[$1] the value of the 3 other strings concatenated, exactly as you were doing in the sprintf().